# Plotting piecewise constant function in Sage gives "no way to make fast_float from None" error

Tags: sagemath

I need to plot following piecewise constant function is Sage:

```
def f(t):
    T = 2.0 * pi

    if t > 0 and t < T / 2.0:
        return 1.0
    elif t == T / 2.0:
        return 0
    elif t > T / 2.0 and t < T:
        return -1.0 

t = var('t')        
p = plot(f(t), (t, 0, 10))
show(p)
```

But `show(p)` gives an error:

```
no way to make fast_float from None
```

The problem is that there is no default returned value in `f(t)`, so the function returns `None` if `t <= 0` or `t >= T`.

The original formula is this one and I can't modify it (so I can't add some default value):
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}1, & 0<t<T/2,\\0, & t=T/2,\\-1, & T/2<t<T\end{cases}
$$

Can somebody help to plot this function? Seems like I need to draw it only in `0 < t < T` interval, but I am out of ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661269/python-no-way-to-make-fast-float-from-none-error/28661486#28661486

I need to leave the `t` and plot just `f` function without a parameter. Also min and max numbers should be in the range of `0 <= t < T`:

```
p = plot(f, (0, 6))
show(p)
```